# how to add variable on pages under Manage Content in Azure Api Management Portal (Developer/Publisher Portal)?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to use one variable in one of the pages under manage content in Azure API Management Portal (Developer/Publisher) Portal. The value of the variable changes as per environment. I did not find anything related to this.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If by variable you mean Named Value - it's currently not possible in a native way.

Comment: I see named Values in API Management to store different values in azure portal. Not sure if we can use them directly in the templates for developer portal.